# Can the system of equations be extracted from its solution?

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

While I was solving the secondary school exam of 2014 I came across a question that states:

After solving those equations: $a_{1}x + b_{1}y = c_{1}$ and $a_{2}x + b_{2}y = c_{2}$, we found that x = $\frac{-7}{\begin{vmatrix}
  3 & 1 \\
  1 & -2
 \end{vmatrix}}$ and y = $\frac{-21}{\begin{vmatrix}
  3 & 1 \\
  1 & -2
 \end{vmatrix}}$, then $c_{1} = .....$ and $c_{2} = .....$

The answer is $c_{1} = 6$ and $c_{2} = -5$ in the ministry's model answers on its website with no steps available ,but it was probably solved by Cramer's rule.

Is this answer right and does $c_{1}$ and $c_{2}$ have only one value?

Answer (score 4):

Presumably the denominator $\left|\matrix{3 & 1\cr 1 & -2}\right|$ indicates that the coefficient matrix $\pmatrix{a_1 & b_1\cr a_2 & b_2} = \pmatrix{3 & 1\cr 1 & -2}$.  Then we have
$$ \pmatrix{c_1 \cr c_2} = \pmatrix{3 & 1\cr 1 & -2} \pmatrix{x\cr y\cr} = \pmatrix{3 & 1\cr 1 & -2} \pmatrix{1\cr 3\cr} = \pmatrix{6\cr -5\cr}$$
agreeing with the ministry's answer.

Comment: Is this mathematically correct? can I deduce the matrix from the determinant? As much as I know the determinant represents only a value,so there's infinity determinants with the same value that could be the coefficient matrix. for example: $\begin{vmatrix}
  -3 & -2 \\
  1 & 3
 \end{vmatrix}$

Comment: You are perfectly right. It is a case where one has to think to the simplest solution ("Occam's razor"), trying to think as the person who has given the problem. Solve it, then make your remark.

Comment: so this answer is as they thought of :D. I was wondering if it's a correct answer "mathematically " @JeanMarie

Comment: That's it. And the ministry is right, by definition.

Comment: The assumption is that they are not trying to fool you: by putting that determinant in the denominator, they are indicating that the solution process involved expressions with that determinant in the denominator.  Of course there are lots of other matrices with the same determinant, but when solving a system of linear equations the most likely reason for evaluating expressions with a determinant in the denominator is that you are using Cramer's rule and the determinant comes directly from the coefficient matrix.

Answer (score 0):

In view of the main determinant:

$$\begin{vmatrix}3 & 1\\1 & -2\end{vmatrix}$$

one may infer that the system is

$$\begin{cases}3x_1+x_2&=&c_1\\1x_1-2x_2&=&c_2\end{cases}$$

Using Cramer's rule (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cramer's_rule), the two numerators can be written under the form:

$$\begin{vmatrix}c_1 & 1\\c_2 & -2\end{vmatrix}=-7 \ \ \text{and} \ \ \begin{vmatrix}3 & c_1\\1 & c_2\end{vmatrix}=-21$$

This can be transformed into a linear system:

$$\begin{cases}-2c_1-c_2&=&-7\\-c_1+3c_2&=&-21\end{cases}$$

Solving this system gives $c_1=6$ and $c_2=-5$, as indicated.

Comment: the main determinant = $\begin{vmatrix}
  3 & 1 \\
  1 & -2
 \end{vmatrix}$ = $\begin{vmatrix}
  a_{1} & b_{1} \\
  a_{2} & b_{2}
 \end{vmatrix}$.does this mean that $a_{1} = 3$ , $a_{2} = 1$, $b_{1} = 1$ and $b_{2} = -2$?If we put $a_{1}$, $a_{2}$, $b_{1}$ and $b_{2}$ with the values -1, 1, 1, 6 respectively the determinant will be the same value and x and y wouldn't change but $c_{1}$ and $c_{2}$ would have different value.

Comment: See my remark above : you have seen that I have used the very diplomatic "one may infer that..." and my colleague has said "Presumably"...

Comment: before that step you presumed that 
x = $\frac{-7}{\begin{vmatrix}
  3 & 1 \\
  1 & -2
 \end{vmatrix}} = \frac{det(A_{1})}{det(A)}$ means that $det(A) = \begin{vmatrix}
  3 & 1 \\
  1 & -2
 \end{vmatrix}$.it's something like saying $\frac{1}{2} = \frac{2}{4}$ means 1 = 2 and 2 = 4.

Comment: and after that you said $\begin{vmatrix}
  3 & 1 \\
  1 & -2
 \end{vmatrix} = \begin{vmatrix}
  a_{1} & b_{1} \\
  a_{2} & b_{2}
 \end{vmatrix}$ means $a_{1} , b_{1} ,  a_{2}, b_{2}$ equals 3, 1, 1, -2.this is also like saying $\begin{vmatrix}
  1 & 1 \\
  1 & 1
 \end{vmatrix} = \begin{vmatrix}
  0 & 0 \\
  2 & 2
 \end{vmatrix}$ means 0 = 1 and 1 = 2.this doesn't seem quite right.